# NetworkX color the nodes in path

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx

How can I color the nodes in the shortest path (in NetworkX library). I found a way to add nodes in different color, but I don't know how to edit the nodes in random graph. I could imagine it being rather easy, but I could not find this part in the documentation. The code below generates a random graph and should calculate the shortest path, if this works perfectly then all i need is to mark that path somehow.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(20, 0.14, seed="303", directed=False)

shortestPath = nx.shortest_path(G, source=G.nodes()[10], target=G.nodes()[0], weight="10")
node = G.graph.get(0)

print(shortestPath)
nx.draw(G)
plt.savefig("path.png")
plt.show()
```

Comment: To color the actual edges of a path see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61821553/9698684

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the color of the nodes in the graph using [`networkx.draw_networkx_nodes`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_nodes). You can color nodes diffrerently by providing a list of colors to `draw_networkx_nodes`, one per node. In your case, you could construct the `node_colors` list as follows:

```
node_colors = ["blue" if n in shortestPath else "red" for n in G.nodes()]
```

Then, you just need to create a layout for your graph (I'm using the [`spring_layout`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.spring_layout.html) in this example), and then draw your graph:

```
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos=pos, node_color=node_colors)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos=pos)
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Thanks! I also found the draw_networkx_nodes/edges, I ended up giving the edges a weight, but your example is much more clear :) Also since the pos gives the position of nodes and not the edges, so now i converted pos in order to give weight to edges.